# Why do my runtime images taken with eztrace not show the idleness of threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, trace

I was doing a college work parallelizing a code in C with OpenMP and then getting a runtime image with eztrace, converting and displaying on vite.

But it's not showing the idle time on threads.
[image: Visualização com vite]

My code obviously has an idle thanks to the use of static clause

```
int prime_v2(int n)
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int prime;
  int total = 0;

  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) private(j,prime) shared(total)
  for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
  {
    prime = 1;
    for (j = 2; j < i; j++)
    {
      if (i % j == 0)
      {
        prime = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    #pragma omp atomic
    total = total + prime;
  }
  return total;
}
```

As can be seen, as **i** increases, increases the total number of inner loop iterations, requiring more time.

With the static division (for 4 threads for example), each thread gets a 'organized' range of iterations:

- **thread 0:** 0    ~ n/4 - 1
- **thread 1:** n/4  ~ n/2 - 1
- **thread 2:** n/2  ~ 3n/4 -1
- **thread 3:** 3n/4 ~ n

That is, the thread 3 caught iterations that require more time. But this idleness is not shown in the vite. Why?

Here how I performed, converted and exibit the vite:

```
eztrace -t omp ./programa
eztrace_convert -t PAJE /tmp/rafael_eztrace_log_rank_1
vite eztrace_output.trace
```

Comment: What compiler and what were the compile options and optimization level?

Comment: Did you compile with the system compiler or did you use the `eztrace_cc` wrapper?

Comment: I compiled with `gcc -o programa code.c -fopenmp`

Comment: Then you are only seeing the intercepted calls to `GOMP_parallel_start` and `GOMP_parallel_end`. With the implicit barrier in the latter, the trace shows exactly what it should.

Comment: Why don't you try compiling with optimization (`-O3`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was with the eztrace version of debian repository

I downloaded an older version and its worked fine. (some with the binary eztrace.old)

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile your application with eztrace_cc: instead of compiling it with

```
$ gcc -o programa programa.c -fopenmp
```

use

```
$ eztrace_cc gcc -o programa programa.c -fopenmp
```

A simple way to do this is to modify your makefile and set

```
CC=eztrace_cc gcc
```

You can take a look at the OpenMP tutorial on the EZTrace webpage:
http://eztrace.gforge.inria.fr/tutorials/tutorial_openmp/